# How are stoppage time goals deduplicated from regulation time goals?

Tags: rules, football, terminology, scoring

In football, goals can be scored in stoppage time, say the 46th minute of the first half, and also in the 46th minute of the game in the second half.

Is there any way of differentiating / deduplicating the stoppage time and regulation time goals? Has there ever been a collision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plus sign (+) is used to indicate goals scored in the stoppage times. For example a goal scored in the 47th minute of the first half is recorded to be scored on 45+2' (the ' is shorthand for minute), where as if it was scored on the 47th minute of the second half, it would've simply been recorded to be scored on 47'.

Same format follows for the stoppage time in the second half and the extra times.

Here on the scoresheet of the round of 16 game between Belgium and Japan in 2018 World Cup you can see Belgium's third goal scored by Chadli recorded to be scored on 90+4'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As @alamoot noted, if the goal was scored during the stoppage time, you will mostly see `45+x'` (similarly `90+x'`, `105+x'` and `120+x'`) notation, however, sometimes goals scored during the stoppage time are counted as last minute goals of the current half, e.g. a goal scored in the 3rd minute of the stoppage time of the second half will be simply denoted with `90'`.

Comment: Goals during the stoppage time after the second half are always scored on 90+x minute, never on 90'.

Comment: @FairPlayer, e.g. here in [livescores.com](http://www.livescores.com/worldcup/match/?match=1-2059636), although Chadli scored his goal in `90+4'`, it's denoted simply as `90'`.

Comment: There are about 100 matches on this page, which one do you mean? And remember that this page is not official.

Comment: @FairPlayer, please follow the embedded link, it's particularly linked to the match played between Belgium and Japan. There's no such thing as official way of keeping record of goal minutes, no official football body regulates this kind of football punctuation. It's just one of the commonly utilized standards.

Comment: So, now on PC it's linked to a particular match. On the Iphone I saw a page with hundreds of matched from all over the world played on that day. But 90` is shown only in match details. In comments it's 90+4'. Writing 90' for stoppage time  can lead to [two goals in one minute](http://www.livescores.com/worldcup/match/?match=1-2059617).

Comment: @FairPlayer yes exactly, but still some use this notation.